# Footer overlapping content in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

I have a page where the footer is overlapping the content in internet explorer 6. I am attaching paths to screenshot, css files.

http://shivanand.in/temp/overlapping-footer.gif
http://shivanand.in/temp/skin.css

http://shivanand.in/temp/skin-ie.css

I am trying to solve since 2 hours without a solution. I need to fix it today. Please let me know if you have a solution.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the HTML you are using?

Comment: It is a jsp page. Can I send the generated source code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Footerstick](http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/)

The second version, not the first one. It woks with both long and short content.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much without knowing the (X)HTML layout, but it seems your content has an absolute position.

Absolutely positioned elements don't affect the page layout, therefore it's normal that your footer is above the content.

Answer (score 0):

You might apply

> clear:both

to the footer.